# Why does the Entity Framework sometimes not include navigation properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I am currently developing web application using help of EF6 for my data management.

**Important to note...** lazy-loading is enabled, no possibility to set it actually off *(it has been introduced into application in earlier times. We are talking about legacy application)*. Returning entities received from repositories are mapped into view models within help of Automapper (7.0.1), which are then passed into a view. Since I am using Automapper I found out the best option to assure, that my properties in my source will be available, is using Eager-loading – using `Include()` method. So I am mixing these two logic - eager-loading whenever possible, rest is using lazy-loading.

> **So what´s the problem?**
>
> Sometimes my navigation properties are not properly loaded and in my
>   given view-models my properties are null. It occurs randomly. **HOWEVER**,
>   if i start debugging *(just insert a breakpoint somewhere)*, the properties are displaying properly. Is it
>   something mysterious hiding behind EF6? Could it be problem with
>   Automapper? Every mention could help.

---

Mapped entity `UserEmailMessage`, which includes navigation properties: `Recipient`, `User` and self-referenced property `ReplyUserEmailMessage`

```
 public class UserEmailMessage
    {
        //abbreviated for clarity
        public int UserEmailMessageId{ get; set; }
        public virtual User Recipient { get; set; }
        public virtual User Sender { get; set; }
        public virtual UserEmailMessage ReplyUserEmailMessage { get; set; }
    }
```

Entity `User` inherits from `IdentityUser` since I am using ASP.NET Identity for memberhip management.

```
public class User : IdentityUser<long, MyLogin, MyUserRole, MyClaim>
{
    //abbreviated for clarity
    public virtual List<UserEmailMessage> UserMessages { get; set; }
}
```

Query data from my repository

```
public UserEmailMessage TestEmailMessage(Expression<Func<UserEmailMessage, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return context.UserEmails.Where(predicate)
                .Include(p => p.Recipient).Include(p => p.Sender).Include(p => p.ReplyUserEmailMessage)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Mapped entity with given Automapper profile

```
     public class EntityProfile : Profile
        {
            public EntityProfile()
            {
                CreateMap<UserEmailMessage, EmailMessageViewModel>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.RecipientId, source => source.MapFrom(sc => sc.Recipient.Id))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.SenderEmail, source => source.MapFrom(sc => sc.Sender.Email))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.SenderFirstName, source => source.MapFrom(sc => sc.Sender.FirstName))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.SenderLastName, source => source.MapFrom(sc => sc.Sender.LastName))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.RecipientEmail, source => source.MapFrom(sc => sc.Recipient.Email));
            }
        }
```

As I mentioned before, result is sometimes not including navigation properties. **However, with breakpoint and debugging, the result is always properly displayed.**

Sometimes I am getting this bad result in a view (within use of view model). I replace empty results with explicit word *empty*. Only `RecipientId` is included in bad result.

```
//@Model.EmailMessageViewModel.RecipientId
RecipientId:182                         
//@Model.EmailMessageViewModel.SenderEmail                 
SenderEmail: empty
//@Model.EmailMessageViewModel.SenderFirstName      
SenderFirstName:empty
//@Model.EmailMessageViewModel.SenderLastName  
SenderLastName:empty
//@Model.EmailMessageViewModel.RecipientEmail
RecipientEmail:empty
```

Comment: One thing I would check for is any code in the application that might attempt to re-attach an entity to the dbContext. What is the lifetime of the dbContext within the repository? Is there an IoC container providing it as a dependency?  If any code is serializing/deserializing or new-ng up and attaching an incomplete entity to the context it may possibly explain how retrieving an entity later down the road would return null references.

Comment: If you use Map you might want to try ProjectTo instead.

Comment: @StevePy Your point directed me quite on the right path. I didnt find out how it was possible, but I figured out, that entity is somehow re-attached as you pointed. Well I solved (for a moment) by adding AsNoTracking () to the method that retrieves the entity. So I deattached the entity from the context to ensure that nothing would change her. However, it makes even more curious to find and fix that error.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Yeah, I know about this kind of projection. However I am not a big fan of it. I do not like mixing mapping logic right in my repository. But It certainly has its case of use. Nevertheless as I commented above, AsNoTracking() helped.